# Why puts is not working in the following code?

Tags: c, function, struct, pass-by-reference, puts

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test
{
    int id;
    char name[20];
};

int main()
{

struct test t1;

   t1.id=1;
   fflush(stdin);
   fgets(t1.name,20,stdin);

   print((&t1.name));          
   print1(t1.id,&(t1.name));    

}
void print(struct test *name)
{
    puts(name);
}

void print1(struct test id,struct test *name)
{

    printf("\n%d\n",id);


    puts(name);
}
```

When I run this program it asks for input

test[enter]

output comes out

test
1
(then program terminates)

Why the first puts worked and why puts in second function did not? Yes, there is an option to send complete structure, but I want to know what's wrong here.

Comment: For a start `fflush(stdin);` is incorrect. Remove it.

Comment: perhaps compiling with all the warnings on would help

Comment: i have started using flush when there is a need to take many string variable simultaneously for example string1,string2 with fgets .if i dont use fflash() the input of string is wierd

Comment: @EdHeal Doesn't help if the OP doesn't pay attention to the warnings. Does any compiler not give warnings for this code?

Comment: So you wish flush to be psychic and know what to ignore? I am afraid you have to read all the input and get you program to decide what to ignore/keep

Comment: @hvd - I agree - but from the question one does not know what warnings have been enabled

Comment: @EdHeal My point is warnings should be emitted by default by any worthwhile compiler in this case, without specifically enabling anything. Therefore, I see three possibilities. 1) The OP is already getting warnings, but is ignoring them. 2) The OP specifically suppressed warnings. 3) The OP is using a horrible compiler that silently accepts this code by default. I think you're focusing on that last possibility, right? I don't consider that very likely, but if there's an example of a real-world compiler that by default silently accepts this, then I'll agree.

Comment: @hvd - As we are not sure of the compiler (perhaps via and IDE) we do not know. VS for example does not have by default all the warnings turned on nor does it change warnings to errors.

Comment: i am using codeblock compiler . and thanks i will not ignore the warning from now onwards:)

Comment: @ekaf Code::Blocks is an IDE, not a compiler. You probably are using GCC as the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not work for several reasons:

- **You are calling functions that lack forward declarations** - you should see warnings when your program compiles. Do not ignore them
- **Your functions are taking arguments of incorrect type** - you should receive the type corresponding to individual fields, e.g. `void print1(int id, char *name)` or you should pass the whole structure, by value or by pointer, i.e. `void print1(struct test t)`

Once you fix these two problems, and make sure that your program compiles warning-free, with all compiler warnings enabled, the issue should be solved.

Comment: Perhaps adding to switch on all the warnings.

Comment: thanks that worked .My 2 more question .first i didnt get where i lack forward declaration 2nd why doest the first                                     print(struct test *name) {puts(name)}                                                 working ?

Comment: @ekaf The first `puts` works by accident. Unfortunately, this is a common thing in C - since the language is so low-level, very often an incorrect program would produce something that resembles correct output. This is called undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
void print(struct test *name)
```

should be changed to

```
void print(char name[]) // because you wish to print a null terminated array of characters.
```

```
 print((&t1.name));
```

should be changed to

```
print(t1.name); //name is the array you wish to print
```

Comment: `print((t1.name);` perhaps `print(t1.name);`

Comment: @EdHeal : Thankyou Ed, as always :)

Comment: what if my requirement is to send it as a refernce so that i can make changes in that function before printing ?

Comment: Arrays when passed to functions are accepted as pointers inside the function, there is no harm changing say `name[2]` to `S` inside the function. However, If you don't wish the changes to reflect outside the `print` function, then you need to create a new `char*` allocate memory for that and use `strcpy` to copy the actual string to the temporary string, change only the temporary string inside the fn.

Answer (score 0):

You need this

```
void print(char *name)
{
    puts(name);
}
```

And the call needs to be

```
print(t1.name);
```

`puts` takes `char *` (or actually `const char *`).

t1.name has the data type `char *`

Similarly

```
void print1(struct test id, char *name)
{

    printf("\n%d\n",id);


    puts(name);
}
```

and the call

```
print1(t1.id,& t1.name);
```

The name of an array degenerates into the address of the first element of an array . So when `t1.name` is passed to function, it becomes the address of the start of the char array.